# Accessing data returned by GET request using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, get, request

Hi I'm trying to use Javascript to write a chrome application that will show your last number of tweets but I'm having trouble getting the tweets. I'm a newbie to javascript but I have searched quite a bit and can't find an understandable answer to this.

From chrome and twitter I have the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
"GET",
"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?
include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=3")
</script>
```

This GET request works but how do I use the data it returns with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhere in `req.responseText`. That is, you need to set `req.onreadystatechange` and once it's ready you'll have it in there.

Answer (score 1):

The result is in the req.responseText. You can append it o your document, to see what the response is. It actually depends on what is the response. I mean maybe you need to alert the response, or show it somewhere, or put it in a condition operator and compare with something... Some basoc use:

`alert(req.responseText);`
`document.body.innerHTML+=req.responseText;`